# PHP session loses information

Tags: php, session

I am passing my session ID thru a flash file to a php file and I am capturing the session ID on the other side and replace the newly generated ID by the old one.

```
$SID = $_GET['mysession'];
session_id($SID);
session_start();
```

Unfortunately the session is now empty and I don't get why.

```
print_r($_SESSION);
```

returns just a 1. All variables from the session are empty/do not exists.

Anyone an idea how to catch the data again?

PHP Version 5.2.6-1+lenny12 with Apache.

Thanks
David

Comment: Have you checked that the value of `$SID` is consistent?

Comment: This smells of session fixation vulnerability!

Comment: $SID is consistent. It is exactly the same like in get and cookie value.

Comment: Better rename your session ID identifier name with [`session_name`](http://php.net/session_name).

Comment: try printing this $_GET['mysession'] and see what is the output?

Comment: It is the session ID and matches the one in the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use session_start(); before you set anything in the session.

Comment: Unfortunately this makes no difference in the result. Still no value in the session.

Answer (score 0):

use it like this,

```
session_start();
$SID = $_GET['mysession'];
session_id($SID);
```

This says, enable session handling on this page and starts a session. after that you are fetching your previous session id and then assigning the same session id to this session. 
Hope, it helps you.

Comment: please do not reply without testing. try it before marking answer not usefull.

Comment: if you call session_id before session_start it will return you nothing.